# TSQL Search by date statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a statement where I am passing a date in the following format `mm/dd/yyyy`

My query is:

```
 SELECT A.[id],
           A.[subject],
           A.[description],
           A.[startTime],
           A.[endTime],
           A.[whoCreated]
   FROM   Focus_Meetings AS A
   WHERE
        (A.[startTime] = COALESCE(@meetingDate, A.[startTime]) OR
         A.[endTime]= COALESCE(@meetingDate, A.[endTime])
        )
    FOR    XML PATH ('details'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

The column for startTime and endTime are both `DATETIME`

How can I get my query to check if the data provided exists in one of those columns?

When I tried the code provided, nothing was returned even though there was a record with the date I used.

Comment: Why did you tag this `mysql` when it's about `tsql`?

Comment: pass date in sql date format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: the format did not return results either

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are `DATETIME`, you might want to cast both the @meetingDate and the columns to `DATE` type and then compare.  You might be matching on date but not matching on time.

Comment: How would I go about changing the type of field for the query?

Comment: You should be able to just `CAST`:  `CAST(A.startTime AS DATE) = CAST(COALESCE(@meetingDate, A.startTime) AS DATE)`

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the value you are passing in @meetingDate which may contain only Date part whereas your StartTime or EndTime in table row, might have time as well. Try to convert A.StartTime and A.EndTime like below:

```
 Convert(varchar,A.StartTime,103) = COALESCE(@meetingDate, Convert(varchar,A.StartTime,103))
```